# NumPy: Merge two arrays in a way that all the values from the first one are saved but only a few from the second array

Tags: python, numpy, bigdata, numpy-ndarray

So, I have two Numpy arrays. One has hundred thousands of values and the other only a few thousands.

So, let's say the first array has 500 thousand values and the other one 8 thousand. These 8 thousand values are also part of the bigger array. So we can say that the second one is a  subset of the biggest array.

I want to do something like a merge with these two arrays, but I want to specify the number of values on the output. Basically, I want a new array that has all the 8K values and another 2K values from the biggest array. I'm not sure if there is a possible way to do that.

NOTE: The chosen values should be unique (not existent in the second array)

```py
first_arr = [3, 5, 8, 10, 14, 15, 16, 18]
second_arr = [5, 10, 15]

# The merged array should have 5
merged_arr = [3, 5, 10, 15, 18]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know exactly how you want the numbers from the second array to be selected, but you could do something like:

```
import random
first_arr = [3, 5, 8, 10, 14, 15, 16, 18]
second_arr = [5, 10, 15]
third_arr = [x for x in first_arr if x not in second_arr]
arr_to_add = random.sample(third_arr, 5-len(second_arr))
result = np.array(list(second_arr) + list(arr_to_add))
```

Note that this might give repeated numbers in your resulting array, im not sure if you want that.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Comment: No, I want unique values, not repeated ones. That's the challenge. About the way of selection, would be great if the values are distributed along the array.

Comment: You mean that they go into the resulting array by way of order in the first_arr? You want to add them in order unless they are in second_arr? If the order doesnt matter (like in your example, where the 8 is skipped) you can use random.sample instead of random.choice.

Comment: Ooh I get what you mean now sorry, you would first have to remove all the values that are in the second array and then make a sample.:

third_arr= [x for x in first_arr if x not in second_arr]

Comment: Yes, t makes sense like that. It didn't think about removing the values and then choosing from it. So in this way we make sure it is unique.

Comment: How can I make equal distributed choices in Numpy?